# Unix bash Sed command Combination on one file

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a file containing strings delimited by any of the following undesired characters:

1. `<`
2. `>`
3. `|`
4. *<space>*

It looks like this:

```
...  > Test Item|Test Item ...
```

The above *...* ellipses represent continuation. The file is comprised of only a single line.

I would like to modify the file so that the strings are delimited instead with only a single *<space>* char. For example:

```
... Test Item Test Item ...
```

With `sed` I tried:

```
sed -e 's/< >*| */|//g' filename
```

But that returned the following error message:

```
sed: 0602-404 Function s/<  *| */|//g cannot be parsed.
```

What to do?

Comment: What do you want to remove?

Comment: `tr -d '<>| ' <filename`

Comment: there is an extra `/` in your sed function (you have four unescaped `/`, it sould be 3).

Comment: @mikeserv if possible please answer the modified question just for knowledge purpose.

Comment: Like,,, `<file1 tr '<>|' '   ' | tr -s \  `... Are you asking me to post an answer or are you saying you didn't like the comment...? It's not clear to me...

Comment: @mikeserv no your comments are equal to answer but if you answer the question the stuff will be more clear to me :)

Comment: @Aman - would you say I correctly interpreted your intent in the edit I made to your question?

Comment: @mikeserv yes you have made correct edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no chance that any of the characters `<> |` might occur within the data you wish to retain in your file, then almost definitely the most efficient solution is simply to `tr`ansliterate them away entirely:

```
tr '<>|' '   ' <infile |    ###translate all delimiter chars to spaces
tr -s ' '     >outfile      ###pipe results to second tr and squeeze spaces
```

`sed` *may* work for you as well, but if it does, it will almost definitely be slower in doing so. You should be careful when working w/ input files not based around `\n`ewline delimiters and using tools designed to handle `\n`ewline delimited data *(such as `sed` and `grep`)* because some implementations may collapse under buffer strain.

Your issue is not *(yet)* that, though: rather you have submitted invalid syntax as a `sed` command. @Archemar has already commented on what it is, but here is why:

A `sed` `s///`ubstitution is a command composed of three fields:

1. the `s` command primitive followed by a delimiter *(typically `/`)*
2. the regular expression pattern field followed by the same delimiter
3. the replacement field followed by the delimiter and optional flags

Either or both of the latter two may be zero-length for different reasons - and so `s///` is *(context-depending)* acceptable syntax. This means that the `sed` parser must depend very heavily on the delimiter. In your command you specify too many fields - which is a syntax error, and is why your *function cannot be parsed*.

If your implementation's `sed` can handle the single-line input and is POSIX-compatible, then this should work instead:

```
sed 'y/<>|/   /;s/  */ /g' <infile >outfile
```

...where the `y` primitive above is `sed`'s own `tr`ansliteration function.

Comment: I have tried your solution , I created three files first file which contains my contents 'A' , the infile and outfile but it is not working,please guide me

Comment: @Aman - well, *infile* and *outfile* are merely placeholders for your actual filenames. If your file is named `A` and you want the modified results in `B` then this should work: `<A tr '<>|' '   ' | tr -s ' ' >B`. You might also leave off the `>`output redirection entirely at first and just print the results to your terminal screen to get an idea for how it will look in your file like: `<A tr '<>|' '   ' | tr -s ' '`

Comment: hats off to your generosity sed statement that you mentioned is working perfectly.

Comment: @Aman - that is good to hear, but the `tr` solution really should be preferred. If you're copy/pasting from a comment then make sure that you do the right number of spaces for the first `tr`'s second argument - the comments squeeze whitespace and so it may not come across correctly. Try just `tr '<>|' '[ *]' <A` which is another way of specifying multiple replacement targets.  If you successfully clear all `<>|` then try it again and add `| tr -s ' '` to its tail and look for all space sequences to be squeezed to a single space. If 2  doesn't work, `| xargs` might suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
sed -e 's:<>\s\|.*:Replaced:g' filename
```

That's how the result looks like:

```
$ echo "<> |" | sed -e 's:<>\s\|.*:Replaced:g'
Replaced
```

If you just want to remove it, delete word `Replaced` from the command.

If there is an space between symbols `<` and `>`, you should replace `<>` with `<\s>`.

**After the question update**:

```
$ cat filename
  > Test Item|Test Item
  < Test Item|Test Item

$ cat filename | sed -E 's:[<>]\s(.*)\|(.*)$:\1 \2:g'
  Test Item Test Item
  Test Item Test Item
```

Comment: if possible please answer the improved question just for knowledge purpose.

Comment: @Aman Done, checkout.

Comment: it is giving error sed: 0602-404 Function s:[<>]\s(.*)\|(.*)$:\1 \2:g cannot be parsed.

Comment: You should copied something wrong or misspelling something. I tested in on ubuntu and osx, and works on both (on sed version 4.2.2).

Comment: @jherran - that's most likely GNU `sed` - which isn't OSX's default `sed` anyway - but the asker tags for `ksh` and the *function cannot be parsed* is not the kind of error a GNU `sed` would print at all. `sed -E` is almost definitely not going to work. Try installing the *heirloom toolchest* package and manufacture your regex for compatibility with its included `sed`, or else visit the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for `sed` and use it as a guide. In any case, `sed` is a line-oriented tool and the single line input file does not bode well for its application.